# load .npz file in python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I generated a dataset about 7 hours and saved it as

```
np.savez("/content/gdrive/My Drive/allc.npz", all=all, lab=lab)
```

Then, I opened and check the file

```
d=np.load("/content/gdrive/My Drive/allc.npz")
all=d["all"]
l=d["lab"]
all.shape
```

And, it worked perfectly

But, today, i opened the file using np.load it shows

```
BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

What is happened and what to do. Any suggestion

Thank you

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Your problem seems to be that your original working .npz file has been overwritten, replaced, or corrupted.  Most likely you overwrote it by mistake.

Comment: Ok, do you know how to resolve it... Thanks

Comment: You should restore the correct file from your backup system, or re-run the program which generated it in the first place if you don't have backups.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that the `.npz` file is not fully available to start working, as mentioned in the first comment.

In my case, I wanted to load a local `.npz` file on a google Colab, while uploading I tried to load it and received the `BadZipFile: File is not a zip file` error. Later, I realized the uploading circle was still incomplete.

So make sure `.npz` is fully available.

Comment: The same problem when working locally. A little patience after creating the file to load it again was enough :)